# How to install gcc4.4.7 in the ubuntu15.10?

Tags: 14.04, gcc

I had try to install gcc4.4 and g++4.4 but will print out "E: Package 'gcc-4.4' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'g++-4.4' has no installation candidate" in the ubuntu15.10?

Comment: Why to not just install `sudo apt-get install g++`?

Comment: The ubuntu15.10 already install gcc4.7, but I need gcc4.4 and g++4.4 to build android.

Comment: hm… are you sure 4.7 is not okay? Because I think it is hard to write a code which would be compiled with 4.4 but not 4.7. Though NVidia [somehow magically managed to do…](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6622751/2388257) Anyway, that old version [is not available for Ubuntu-15.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-4.&searchon=names&suite=wily&section=all). You'd probably try to find some PPA with the old compiler version, or build the compiler by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Getting g++-4.4, gcc-4.4 with Ubuntu15.10 : Add one line to /etc/apt/sources.list , like : `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Text to be added, (with my example URL) :

deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe

... Then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install g++-4.4`
 ... and you have : `/usr/bin/{ gcc-4.4, g++-4.4 }`.

---

Other Ubuntu extra gcc versions https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing

Comment: I seem to understand that, trusty server  can get  gcc4.4 , but where to know the various versions of the Ubuntu support which GCC?

Comment: Compilers built with Ubuntu 11.10 or later can usually be used as is. They all use the "new path´s" , like /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/** . Earlier compilers e.g. gcc.3.4.6 must be rebuilt with links to those files. → compat-gcc34-3.4.6-ubuntu1204-1_amd64.deb → https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNRTkzQnRSNXZ6UVU/view?usp=sharing