# Error in installation of gcc-4.6 and gcc++-4.6 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gcc

I am getting following error in installing the older version of gcc(which I require unfortunately)

[image: ubb]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [no official GCC 4.6 package for 16.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gcc-4.6); the lowest version available is [4.7](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gcc-4.7). If you really need 4.6, you will have to use [Ubuntu 14.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gcc-4.6), or find a PPA which provides it for 16.04.

Comment: I got this PPA link https://launchpad.net/~h-rayflood/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-upper . Now how to install it from this link?

Comment: @NaseerAhmed This PPA does not provide packages for Xenial. I also recommend you read about what PPAs are and how to use them (just Google it or something).

Comment: The question has been answered before :  http://askubuntu.com/questions/786315/how-to-install-gcc4-4-7-in-the-ubuntu15-10/786424#786424 .... Same solution for Ubuntu 16.04 :  Works OK in my Ubuntu 16.04 computers.

Comment: @KnudLarsen If you are going to add the Trusty repositorties, then you should definitely also add `trusty-updates` and `trusty-security`.